Confusion about central limit theorem by Chandrasekhar et al
In this paper by Chandrasekhar et al. (General Covariance-Based Conditions for Central Limit Theorems with Dependent Triangular Arrays) we can find the following CLT (for simplicity paraphrased in dimension $d = 1$):
Suppose $(Z_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}$ is a (possibly dependent) sequence of random variables with $\mathbb E\left[Z_i \sum_{j\neq i} Z_j|\sum_{j\neq i} Z_j\right] \geq 0$ (a) for all $i$, and

$\sum_{i,j} \text{Cov}(Z_i^2, Z_j^2) = o(|\Omega_n|^2)$,
$\sum_{i\neq j} \text{Cov}(Z_i, Z_j) = o(|\Omega_n|)$,

where $\Omega_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var} Z_i$. Then $\Omega_n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \to \mathcal N(0, 1)$ in distribution.
The $Z_i$ may also depend on $n$, I left this out for brevity. This is their Corollary 1. Directly below they write "If $\mathbb E\left[Z_i Z_j|Z_j\right]\geq 0$ (b) does not hold, then 2. can just be substituted with [some other Assumption]".
It sounds like they are implying some sort of relation between (a) and (b) (with some quantifiers added), but don't really see it since conditioning on a sum is very different from conditioning on all its summands. So maybe it's just a typo. However, in 3.2.2. they say 'We can [...] apply Corollary 1. [...]. It is easy to see that $\mathbb E[Z_t Z_s|Z_s]\geq 0$" and they don't say anything else about (a) which seems to suggest that they do think (b) (with $\forall i\neq j$) implies (a) somehow.
Does it? Or am I misinterpreting what they are saying in some way?
PS: I have e-mailed them directly but have gotten zero responses.
